# WPF C# Datagrid keep showing the path of the datasource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Mine Datagrid keep showing this kinda datasource context. I try to hide its but no avail cannot hide it in the end.

sorry for the broken english as its not mine native language.

here the image of the problem.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6qAn.png)

and here mine code :

```
private void fill_table_IP()
        {

            Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, string>> data_IP = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, string>>();

            _dataTable = new DataTable("Table1");
            _dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ip"));
            _dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("type"));
            _dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("status"));
            _dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("id"));
            data_IP = Get_IP_Form_table();

            foreach (KeyValuePair<int, Dictionary<string, string>> item in data_IP)
            {
                _dataTable.Rows.Add(item.Value["IP_Address"], item.Value["Type_Of_Connection"],   item.Value["Status_Connection"],
                    item.Value["Inventory_ID"]);
               

            }

            _dataTable.DefaultView.Sort = "ip ASC";
            _dataTable = _dataTable.DefaultView.ToTable();
            
            tb_IP.ItemsSource = null;
            tb_IP.ItemsSource = _dataTable.DefaultView;



        }
```

Well i just want to hide this datasource context in datagrid view.

Comment: How many items are there in data_IP?

Comment: I don't think you need that TotTable() line.  It's just duplicating a datatable to itself. 

 What's your xaml look like?

 Is there any more code you're not showing us that references that datagrid?  It kind of looks like you're appending another datarowview into items somehow.

Comment: Remove styles etc. from data grid, also remove `DataGrid.Columns` with its content, set `AutoGenerateColumns="True"`. The content of table must be OK.